# Set binary mode after file is opened

Tags: c

My function

```
void myFunction (FILE *f);
```

gets an already opened file. I need to write a literal `CR+LF`, so I want to set `f`'s mode to binary.

How can I do that?

Comment: There should be no difference inf opening a file in binary or text mode. You should be able to `fwrite("\r\n", 2, 1, stream);` without any problems.

Comment: You don't specify an OS, but maybe `setmode` (or `_setmode`) is a possible?

Comment: @H2CO3 On Windows you'll end up with `\r\r\n` in text mode.

Comment: @Corbin Who told you Windows had a conforming C implementation?

Comment: @H2CO3 No arguement that Microsoft's C is rather spotty in terms of standard adherence, but it's actually implementation defined behavior. Section 5.2.2: `Each of these escape sequences shall produce a unique implementation-deﬁned value
which can be stored in a single char object. The external representations in a text ﬁle
need not be identical to the internal representations, and are outside the scope of this
International Standard.`

Comment: @Corbin Fair enough. I'd rather still not bother with Windows being crappy (yay, that's personal opinion, but you get the point -- on any sane system, I'd expect that my programs do what I told them to do, and not some random unreasonable behavior...)

Comment: @Corbin (Also, AFAIK there are other reasons why Microsoft's C compiler is not conformant, but I need to check it yet.)

Comment: @RogerRowland I'm currently using gcc on Debian GNU/Linux, but I would like it to work also on Windows (I suppose I'll compile it with MinGW). (I didn't find `setmode` or `_setmode`.)

Comment: @H2CO3 It's conformant for the most part, but they have a fun habit of 'deprecating' standard functions in favor of their own. It's very annoying. And if opened in binary mode, it will write byte for byte. It's just Windows happens to take text mode to heart :/. \r\n has always seemed like one of the worst decisions ever made, but eh, nothing we can do about it now. If you're stuck on Windows, you're stuck on Windows.

Comment: @Corbin Sure, for some people it's an obligation, not a choice. I feel sorry for them, honestly.

Comment: @H2CO3 You'll be excited to hear that the new CL in VS2013's RC has "more key features of the C99 standard" Yeah, and it only took 14 years to get even *those*.

Comment: @WhozCraig :D :D We can still "no haz `snprintf()`", though. Or can we?

Comment: @angus [MSDN link to `_setmode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tw4k6df8.aspx) for Windows. The POSIX equivalent `setmode` [is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235459.aspx) on Windows (see @Corbin comment).

Comment: @RogerRowland If your solution is to use `_setmode` enclosed by `#ifdef`'s (which?), put it as an answer and I'll accept it if nothing more portable comes up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments, perhaps a function such as the following may be useful (untested!) :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifdef WIN32
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>
#endif

int SetBinary(FILE *pFile)
{
    // set file mode to binary
#ifdef WIN32
    return _setmode(_fileno(pFile), O_BINARY);
#else
    return setmode(_fileno(pFile), O_BINARY);
#endif
}
```

It looks ugly, so maybe you might conditionally `#define` the function name instead, but I don't think it's ever going to be pretty.

Comment: Neither `setmode` nor `_fileno` exist in my system, but they are not needed, because it's not Windows (AFAIUI). So, you maybe should delete the `#else` part of your `#ifdef`.